# I need to store the values in variables from dynamic object array in Swift

Tags: json, swift, swift3

This is my JSON. The keyfields have n length & based on key length the array object value also increase:

```
{
  "key_fields": [
    {
      "fieldName": "xxxxx"
    },
    {
      "fieldName": "yyyyy"
    }
  ],
  "Array": [
    {
      "xxxxx": 1,
      "yyyyy": 2
    },
    {
      "xxxxx": 3,
      "yyyyy": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: What is your question? What issue are you having?

Comment: explain your problem??

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit vague. I guess you can use a `Tuple` with `Array` like this

```
var result = (key_fields: [], array: [])
result.key_fields.append((fieldName: "xxxxx", fieldName2: 2))
```